# vietnamese email subject encoding?

Tags: c#, email, mime, imaplib

```
Subject: Re:
 =?UTF-8?Q?Th=E1=BA=A7y_g=E1=BB=ADi_b=C3=A0i_t=E1=BA=ADp_cho_em_v=E1=BB?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=9Bi.?=
```

I received an email with this subject header. How should it be decoded?

Comment: Modern email clients will transparently decode encoded words such as this.  Most email frameworks have a mechanism for handling them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [MIME encoded-word](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).  The syntax is `=?`charset`?`transfer-encoding`?`encoded-data`?=`.  Transfer encoding is `B`ase64 or `Q`uoted-printable.

To decode it:

1. Split the encoded word into its 3 parts.
2. Decode the data (3rd part) into `byte[]` according to its transfer encoding (2nd part).  In this case, the Q encoding is used, so replace the `=`*xx* sequences with the corresponding octets.  This gives you the two byte arrays [84, 104, 225, 186, 167, 121, 95, 103, 225, 187, 173, 105, 95, 98, 195, 160, 105, 95, 116, 225, 186, 173, 112, 95, 99, 104, 111, 95, 101, 109, 95, 118, 225, 187] and [155, 105, 46].
3. Decode these byte arrays according to the specified encoding.

In this particular example, both of the encoded-words are *invalid*: The first one is missing a trail byte of a 3-byte UTF-8 character, and the second one starts with a trail byte.  But *combined*, they're valid UTF-8, and decode to the string `Thầy_gửi_bài_tập_cho_em_với.`  (which Google Translates to "Teacher sent me to exercise.")

Comment: Don't forget that raw _'s in the encoded-data section are meant to be replaced with a space character.

Comment: The relevant bit from RFC 2047 [declaring such encoded-words invalid](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047#page-8): `Each 'encoded-word' MUST represent an integral number of characters.
   A multi-octet character may not be split across adjacent 'encoded-word's.`

Answer (score 6):

This is defined in RFC 2047:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047

See section 4 on encodings.  I'm not sure if there's anything in the base framework that handles this/handles this correctly.

Edit: here's one person's attempt at this: http://vsevolodp.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-decode-encoded-word-header.html

Comment: That's my blog post actually :) Let me know if you need some missing functionality.
And feel free to use this code.

Comment: I found yours after we had built ours, would have saved me some work!  Thanks for putting code like this out there on the web though, assuming it's okay to borrow.